# Finding extrema.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, analytic-geometry

Find the minimum distance between point $M(0,-2)$ and points $(x,y)$ such that: $y=\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}\,x^{3}}-2$ for $x>0$ .

I used the formula for distance between two points in a plane to get: $$d=\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{256}{3x^{6}}}$$ And this is where I cannot come up with how to proceed. I tried calculus but the first derivative of $d(x)$ is fairly ugly expression...
A few techniques on how to handle problems on maxima and minima with(out) using calculus would be really useful.

Comment: Minimize $d^2$, that makes things nicer.  As to non-calculus, good idea, but I think it requires more thinking, while differentiation is purely mechanical. One can use AM/GM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that the value of $x$ that minimize  $d$  minimimize also  $d^2=x^2+\dfrac{2^8}{3x^6}=f$ and the derivative is $f'= 2x-\dfrac{2^9}{x^7}$.

Comment: "Note that the minimum of $d$ is also the minimum of $d^2$": I know what you mean, but it's not true; and I think in this context, it's important not to mislead. You mean: A value of $x$ which minimises $d$ also minimises $d^2$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you, I edit

Answer (score 1):

We give a non-calculus approach. It is in my opinion a fair bit harder than the calculus way.

We want to minimize $x^2+\frac{256}{3x^6}$, or equivalently
$$\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{256}{3x^6}.$$
By the arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality (AM/GM) we have
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(  \frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{256}{3x^6}      \right)\ge \sqrt[4]{\frac{x^2}{3}\cdot \frac{x^2}{3}\cdot\frac{x^2}{3}\cdot \frac{256}{3x^6}}\tag{1}$$
with equality when all the terms on the left are equal.  The right-hand side of (1) is $\frac{4}{3}$.  Equality is achieved when $\frac{x^2}{3}=\frac{256}{3x^6}$, that is, when $x=\pm 2$.

We conclude that the square of the distance has minimum value $\frac{16}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, are inequalities the only other non-calculus way of finding extrema? Just curious...

Comment: They are the main way. For more ideas, I recommend looking at Ivan  Niven's very nice book on Maxima and Minima without Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Searching a minimum value for $d^2$. I would say - in point minimum for $d^2$ will be minimized too 'd'.